# Android sending "fake" welcome emails to user

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

In my app, user connects their Google account with my app right after first start, so I want to send them "Welcome mail". Also, there're another cases when I need to send them something. But since I don't want to use some web service, I just want to send these messages directly from app.

So I've been searching Internet and I found this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail_with_the_JavaMail_API
Basicaly, it's part of Google App Engine, but for mailing, they're using JavaMail API. So I've downloaded javax.mail library from here: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release
and I've added it to my Android app.

Then, I've tried to use this code from Google App Engine docs:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

// ...
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

String msgBody = "...";

try {
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
     new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "Mr. User"));
    msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
    msg.setText(msgBody);
    Transport.send(msg);

} catch (AddressException e) {
    // ...
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    // ...
}
```

But that throwed `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler`
I found out I also need to add `javax.activation.jar` from JavaBeans Activation Framework, so I've done so, but that didn't change anything about this error. And that's interesting, because when I type `javax.activation.DataHandler();`, it founds it.

Later, I also found that I need third library - additional.jar, so I've added this as well... but still, it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler` . At this point, I don't know what's the problem...

Comment: Why torture yourself to not use "some web service"? Just use mailchimp or mailgun or whatever. Cheap (or free) and simple to use.

Comment: @GregEnnis well that's the problem, I need free solution. But I looked at web solutions and I found phpMailer -> so would it be somehow possible to set it on some website and then just call its methods from Android?